# What is meant by select() and poll() are stateless?

Tags: c, linux, epoll

I am trying to understand how epoll() is different from select() and poll(). select() and poll() are pretty similar. select() allows you to monitor multiple file descriptors and it checks if any of those file descriptors are available for an operation (e.g. read, write) without blocking. When the timeout expires, select() returns the file descriptors that are ready and the program can perform the operations on those file descriptors without blocking.

```
...
FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(0, &rfds);
/* Wait up to five seconds. */
tv.tv_sec = 5;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
/* Don’t rely on the value of tv now! */

if (retval == -1)
    perror("select()");
else if (retval)
    printf("Data is available now.\n");
    /* FD_ISSET(0, &rfds) will be true. */
else
    printf("No data within five seconds.\n");
...
```

poll() is a little more flexible in that it does not rely on bitmap, but array of file descriptors. Also, since poll() uses separate fields for requested (events) and result (revents), you don't have to worry to refill the sets that were overwritten by kernel.

```
...
struct pollfd fds[2];
fds[0].fd = open("/dev/dev0", ...);
fds[1].fd = open("/dev/dev1", ...);
fds[0].events = POLLOUT | POLLWRBAND;
fds[1].events = POLLOUT | POLLWRBAND;
ret = poll(fds, 2, timeout_msecs);
if (ret > 0) {
    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
        if (fds[i].revents & POLLWRBAND) {    
...
```

However, I read that there is an issue with poll() too since both select() and poll() are stateless; the kernel does not internally maintain the requested sets. I read this:

> Suppose that there are 10,000 concurrent connections. Typically, only
>   a small number of file descriptors among them, say 10, are ready to
>   read. The rest 9,990 file descriptors are copied and scanned for no
>   reason, for every select()/poll() call. As mentioned earlier, this
>   problem comes from the fact that those select()/poll() interfaces are
>   stateless.

I don't understand what is meant by the file descripters are "copied" and "scanned". Copied where? And I don't know what is meant by "stateless". Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Stateless" means "Does not retain anything between two calls". So kernel need to rebuild many things for mainly nothing in the mentioned example.